# Hibernate, repository.save - java.lang.NullPointerException: null - while Object exist

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am writing this code to simply save new data to mySql db, created the class, repository, and main controller, it actually works for one class but not this one, appreciate some pointers as I don't really get why the null pointer:

> Code:
>   main controller:

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/addExchange") 
public @ResponseBody String addNewExchange (@RequestParam String exchange)
{
    //check1
    System.out.println("creating Exchange constructor");
    Exchange e = new Exchange(); 
    //check 2
    System.out.println("created exchange constructor, " + exchange);
    e.setE_name(exchange);
    //check 3
    System.out.println("Exhange name is, " + e.getE_name());
    //check 4
    System.out.println(e);
    exchangeRepository.save(e); 
    return "Saved Exchange";
}
```

> Output error from Eclipse Console:
>   my checks below show object is picked up from the mapping:
>   - creating Exchange constructor
>   - created exchange constructor, **orange**
>   - Exhange name is, **orange**
>   - **Exchange [idexchange=0, e_name=orange]**

2018-05-21 15:59:43.528 ERROR 5118 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.instantmoney.MoneyServices.MainController.addNewExchange(MainController.java:47) ~[classes/:na]

> Exchange Repository:

```
public interface ExchangeRepository extends CrudRepository<Exchange, Long> {
```

}

> Exchange class

```
    @Entity 
public class Exchange {

@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int idexchange; 

private String e_name;

public Exchange() {}
```

//getters and setters

> Curl

```
http://localhost:8080/moneyservice/addExchange?exchange=orange
```

Comment: I think `exchangeRepository` is null, could you add the `MainController` code?

Comment: since we cannot see your original line numbers, please mark this line: MainController.java:47 in your code

Comment: @GetMapping(path = "/addExchange") 
 public @ResponseBody String addNewExchange (@RequestParam String exchange)
 {
  //check1
  System.out.println("creating Exchange constructor");
  Exchange e = new Exchange(); 
  //check 2
  System.out.println("created exchange constructor, " + exchange);
  e.setE_name(exchange);
  //check 3
  System.out.println("Exhange name is, " + e.getE_name());
  //check 4
  System.out.println(e);
  **exchangeRepository.save(e);** 
  return "Saved Exchange";
 }

Comment: Please use @Repository annotation in Repository class and then Autowire it into Controller...It should be work.

Comment: @Eihab you can edit your post to add the code, please not add code in a comment...

Comment: yes that worked actually, I didn't realise I need for each repository annotated it with @Autowire. I can now save the data successfully, however the first record was saved with idexchange = 2 instead of . But thank you the initial problem is now solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@Controller
public class ExchangeController {    

   @RequestMapping(path = "/addExchange", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
   public @ResponseBody String addNewExchange (@RequestParam String exchange)
   {
    if (exchange != null ) {
       Exchange e = new Exchange(); 
       e.setE_name(exchange);
       exchangeRepository.save(e); 
       return "Saved Exchange";
    } else {
       return new BadRequestException("exchange name can not be null!");
    }
   }

   @Autowired
   public ExchangeController(ExchangeRepository exchangeRepository) {
       this.exchangeRepository = exchangeRepository;
   }

   private ExchangeRepository exchangeRepository;
}
```

Comment: I also made use of your help Devratna, to add the !=null was useful, I added this piece of the code to avoid null exceptions. Thank you for your help